# Binding specific column of a record to Image Control

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app, I am sending a string into the page that is being navigated to. I then use that value to find a certain record in my table that comes from an azure mobile service database. The record that is found is stored in 'item'. I'm now hoping you could show me how to take the column 'ImageUri' from 'item' and bind it to 'myImage' in the xaml code.

```
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable =
     App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    try
    {
        string strVal1 = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["value1"];

        var item = todoTable.Where(Record => Record.Text.Contains(strVal1));

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        string error = Convert.ToString(exception);
        MessageBox.Show(error);
    }

}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
        <Grid x:Name="imageGrid">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageTransform" />
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Image Name="myImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Stretch="Uniform"
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<Image Name="myImage" Source={Binding Path=Image}/>
```

And in C#

```
this.DataContext = TodoItem;
```

Assuming your class name where the image URL comes in is Image.